# git : reverts changes other than one specific files

Tags: linux, git

git revert HEAD reverts all changes, but what I want to revert the ones except my go extension files? I want to revert all changes except the one with *.go

I tried

```
   git revert HEAD ^*.go
   git revert HEAD *.go?
```

None of them works. Where should I look up to find this feature?

Thanks~!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a better way, but what should work:

```
git revert --no-commit HEAD
git reset HEAD -- *.go
git checkout -- *.go`
git commit
```

Or you can approach it the other way around and instead of using revert, checkout the files you want to revert from the old commit:

```
git checkout <commit> -- <paths to revert>
git commit
```

Comment: i am getting fatal: bad revision 'HEAD~'  any other way? thanks

Comment: Actually the '~' is wrong there.
But what are you trying to do? Undo a commit? Discard working tree changes only?

Answer (score 0):

I am by no means an expert with piping output into Git commands, but you could try something along the lines of:

```
git checkout HEAD^ -- $(find. -not -path '*.git*' -not -iname '*.go' -type f)
```

The `find` output should consist of all the files that do not have the `go` extension. These files will then be reverted to their state in the last `HEAD`. You may need to add additional `-not` chunks for folders or files you want to ignore.